# Removing reference files from debugging

Tags: javascript, debugging

Is there a way to remove reference files from debugging on any known debugger (preferably browser based)

I'm currently writing in Javascript, and am using several libraries such as THREE.js, and jquery.js, but when debugging I'd like to step over these libraries by default.

Is there any debugger which has this feature (a toggle or a specific step-over function that can be used to remove files from step-into and step-over requests)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firefox can do this with its black box on debugging:

f12 -> debugger -> click the eye symbol next to the name of the source you want to get rid of.